# On CASCADE DELETE impact on Entity Framework to delete child record using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I am new in sql server programming, I have approx 33 tables which are linked together, I have a task to delete primary table e.g. Enquiry record which are soft deleted and need to delete all child record as well.

I have two option first is `CASCADE DELETE` and another start delete with child table record but hard to find which one is last child entry. 
If I go with `CASCADE DELETE`, will this impact on current user or edmx foreign constraint or there is another way to perform this task however I am doing this action in SQL stored procedure.

Comment: What do you mean by **soft delete** here exactly??

Comment: There is a bit type column **IsDeleted**.

Comment: Which means the tuple is not deleted, but marked as delete right?? And also, please post a sample dataset as well. Maybe in an SQLFiddle...

Comment: cascade delete will never work with soft deletes, it only works on real deletes. Be carefull with soft deletes because when using soft delete you have to do everything yourself, not only marking records for delete but also check for every record if i can be deleted based on relations. The database cannot help you anymore with soft deletes, you are on your own. If you are not a skilled sql programmer than dont do soft deletes.

Comment: @GuidoG:; `If you are not a skilled sql programmer...` or give it a try and learn from it ;-)

Comment: No, I just get soft deleted record for hard delete, soft delete is just a flag which will not showing on admin panel after deleted by user but kept in db record.